# Set height for EditText no more than the coordinates of the center screen

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new in Android.

Now I need `EditText` which should be no more than a certain size. Now I try to use this code:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="3" />
```

layout_height="wrap_content" - in this case my `EditText` height is equal to the number of letters in it.

But I need make restriction for height for example set height for `EditText` no more than of center screen.

I know that we have some problem because Android use many of different screen.

Have we got a way for calculate this height. I mean the bottom border of `EditText` should not be more than center of screen.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict an EditText by adding additional values

```
android:maxLines
```

Furthermore you could add

```
android:maxHeight
```

with some kind of dp value.

I wouldn't use other techniques for restricting the height.

Comment: How can I change maxHeight programmatically? Any idea